# Value within a function seems to not be able to detect the local variables and also fails

Tags: kdb

I want to be able to run something like the following:

```
f:{[dt] syms:`sym1;eval parse"select from tbl where date = dt, sym=syms"}
f[.z.D]
```

Given the following :

```
tbl:([] date:2022.01.01 2022.01.01; Id:1000000 2000000; sym:`sym1`sym2;price:10 20;qty:3 4)

f:{[dt] syms:`sym1; ?[tbl;((=;`date;`dt);(=;`sym;`syms));0b;()]}
f1:{[dt] syms:`sym1; (?) . (tbl;((=;`date;`dt);(=;`sym;`syms));0b;())}
f2:{[dt] syms:`sym1; value (?;tbl;((=;`date;`dt);(=;`sym;`syms));0b;())}

f[.z.D]  // works 
f1[.z.D] // Gives Error - dt not recognized/out of scope 
f2[.z.D] // Gives Error - dt not recognized/out of scope
```

Value within a function seems to not be able to detect the local variables and surprisingly (?) . also fails. (maybe because this in itself is a function and dt is not defined here?)

Is there any work around for this?
For context, I have a function that takes a select string/functional select, parses it, does some checks and manipulations on the functional form and returns a modified functional form.
I want users to be able to call this function from their own functions and that parameters they have defined in their function can be in the outputted functional form and that functional form can be valued some how.
I don't want users to be forced to pass more variables into my function etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is remove the backtick for `dt` and `syms`

I would also recommend using a backtick when calling your table name.

Further, you should make sure `syms` is enlisted if it is only one symbol.

So your function should be:

```
f:{[dt] syms:(),`sym1; ?[`tbl;((=;`date;dt);(=;`sym;syms));0b;()]}
```

If you parse your select statement you can see the correct form for functional selects:

```
q)parse "select from tbl where date=2022.01.01,sym=`sym1"
?
`tbl
,((=;`date;2022.01.01);(=;`sym;,`sym1)) // comma in front of `sym1 means enlist
0b
()
```

The backtick is not needed as this is a variable, defined in your function, it would be the same as doing:

```
?[`tbl;((=;`date;2022.01.01);(=;`sym;enlist `sym1));0b;()]
```

This should allow you to use your function correctly:

```
q)f[2022.01.01]
date       Id      sym  price qty
---------------------------------
2022.01.01 1000000 sym1 10    3
```

For more information, see the kx [documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/)

Comment: That won't work if the user has {[x] value parse "select from tbl where date=x"} because once you parse this you get backtick x not the value of x - so I want to have this work with the backticks. From f you can see that it works when you do ```?[tbl;();enlist(=;date;`x);()]``` but not when doing ```(?) . (tbl;();enlist(=;date;`x);())```

I am trying to avoid the user having to do value parse "select from tbl where date=", string[x]

Comment: Can you explain what your restrictions are?
What are the users inputting?
Is this meant to be for any select statement?

Comment: Yeah, sure. At the minute I have a function `myApi` that users call as `myApi"select from tbl where date=dt"` This does a number of things and then returns a new functional form. 
I want users to be able to call this function from within other functions. And potentially pass parameters such as date into their function.
So we'd have userFunc:{[x] value myApi"select from tbl where date = x"}. Now they could do this as ```userFunc:{[x] value myApi"select from tbl where date = ",string[x]}``` - but I'd like it to be as simple as possible for users to use